# How do I remove leading and trailing text in Autohotkey

Tags: string, replace, character, autohotkey, trim

I know this is basic but for the life of me, I am having difficulty. Can someone explain how I can change the following in Autohotkey:

Change:

> VAR = Leading string of text @**TEXT I WANT TO KEEP**@ Trailing String
>   of Text...

To:

> **TEXT I WANT TO KEEP**

In other words I want to keep only what's in between the "@" symbols and then save the result as a variable.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Is it possibly trim or regexreplace?

Answer (score 1):

**Stores `TEXT I WANT TO KEEP` in variable `match1`**

```
VAR := "Leading string of text @TEXT I WANT TO KEEP@ Trailing String of Text"
if RegExMatch(VAR, "@(.*?)@", match) > 0
  MsgBox Found "%match1%"
```

**Reference**

- [RegExMatch](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression is:

```
@(.*?)@
```

The output of which will be stored in `$0`

Comment: Hi, it's just "find", then select "Regular Expression" on the lower left

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
VAR = Leading string of text @TEXT I WANT TO KEEP@ Trailing String of Text...

MsgBox % StrSplit(var, "@").2
```